# Make the Button do not refresh the Aspx Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to do a JavaScript in my WebSite that when i click a button a popup appears, but the Aspx reload the webpage everytime I click a button, the javaScript before the refresh works, but the page is reloaded and the page come back as it was without the popup. Is there any way to make the page do not refresh when I press a HTML button without affecting my aspx button functions?

Here is the HTML/ASPX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqueryui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/myjqTest.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div id="header">
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="loginoptionsButton" CssClass="loginoptionsButton"
    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
    OnClick="loginoptionsButton_Click">LOGIN</asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="signuplogoutButton" CssClass="signuplogoutButton"
    runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
    OnClick="signuplogoutButton_Click">CADASTRAR-SE</asp:LinkButton></li>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <button id="TestJS" class="">Test</button>
        <div id="Popup" class=""></div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("Popup");

test.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (test.className === "Hide") {
        test.className = "";
    } else {
        test.className = "Hide";
    }
});
```

Comment: In your JavaScript what is 'login'?

Comment: sorry the login.addEventListener is actualy test.addEventListener

Comment: So you have an event listener on the pop up itself but which of your buttons are you having the trouble with? What JavaScript function should it run?

Comment: Every button I click refreshes the page... the Script works, but the page is reloaded, and every thing goes back to normal...

Comment: Your buttons are causing postbacks in the page when they run the functions that you have specified in the OnClick, this in turn has the effect of refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
test.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (test.className === "Hide") {
        test.className = "";
    } else {
        test.className = "Hide";
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```